# Docker execution of Symfony commands: Permission denied

Tags: symfony, docker

I am currently setting up a symfony project with docker and need to run some commands via `bin/console`  like this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Currently I'm trying to do this with `docker-compose exec`:

```
 docker-compose exec app bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```

As result, I get this error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bin/console\": permission denied": unknown

I tried using chmod wihin my Dockerfile, but this did not work:

Dockerfile-php

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        libxml2-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY . /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/project/

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data var/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data var/log
RUN chmod +x bin/console
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php 
    environment: 
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxx:xxx@db:3306/project_db # Connection string for the database
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/project/ 
    networks:
      - symfony 
...
```

Any Ideas, how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried running the command using a bash in interactive mode?

Comment: @NicoHaase Kind of, here i geht the error: `bash: php: command not found` which is a bit confusing

Comment: try `docker exec -i  container-id bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists`

Comment: @A.Marwan `"exec: \"bin/console\": stat bin/console: no such file or directory": unknown` strange

Comment: try this then `docker exec -it container-id bin/bash` and inside the container do what you like

Comment: @A.Marwan tried this before, error above

Comment: Can you share more details about your docker file? Looks like you have no PHP installed in it

Comment: @NicoHaase well, I can use the app (that uses php) already. but i edited the post with the full Dockerfile-php that is called from the docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on https://hub.docker.com/_/php/, the docker image you are using (`php:fpm`) does not contain the CLI version, so you should use another image.

And as Docker allows you to do that, you might use a completely different container to run the CLI version **side to side** the container running the webserver, with the common directories mounted to both containers. This helps you to better seperate the different parts

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem but running this command in my terminal solved the problem:

```
chmod +x bin/console
```

chmod +x on a file means, that you'll make it executable.

Comment: I did `chmod +x bin/*` which worked as there were more similar issues.